UpgradeSpringBoot_3_2 recipe not found in rewrite-spring jar file
I have a task to upgrade our project to Spring Boot 3.x. And I chose OpenRewrite tool to help me with this task. However, I'm facing the issue where UpgradeSpringBoot_3_2 recipe can't be found in rewrite-spring jar file
I downloaded the rewrite-spring:5.11.0 jar using Maven with below code snippet.
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.openrewrite.recipe</groupId>
   <artifactId>rewrite-spring</artifactId>
   <version>5.11.0</version>
 </dependency>

...

<plugin>
  <groupId>org.openrewrite.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>rewrite-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>5.32.0</version>
</plugin>

Then I checked the jar file if the below recipe exist using it's full path but it's not there
org.openrewrite.java.spring.boot3.UpgradeSpringBoot_3_2
Is there anything I missed here? I can see there are recipes inside boot3 folder but what I was looking for was not there. I added screenshot of my Intellij IDE encircling the boot3 folder and
UpgradeSpringBoot_3_2 can't be found inside it

Other things I tried is I checked other versions of rewrite-spring by downloading them and checking what's inside boot3 folder and didn't find any UpgradeSpringBoot_3_x recipe
Below is my reference
https://docs.openrewrite.org/recipes/java/spring/boot3/upgradespringboot_3_2

The dependency needs to be part of the plugin configuration as explained in the reference guide you link to yourself.

Follow the documentation, you didn't.
The dependency should be part of your plugin configuration not a regular dependency.
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.openrewrite.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>rewrite-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>5.32.0</version>
  <configuration>
      
    <activeRecipes>
      <recipe>org.openrewrite.java.spring.boot3.UpgradeSpringBoot_3_2</recipe>
    </activeRecipes>
  </configuration>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openrewrite.recipe</groupId>
      <artifactId>rewrite-spring</artifactId>
      <version>5.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>


For some reason you decided to move the dependency as a regular dependency and as such thus aren't following the way it is documented. (Hence not following the documentation).

thanks sir Deinum for the reply! It solved the issue. I followed the documentation earlier but didn't get the desired result so I was experimenting. Nonetheless, it was a mistake on my part to delve away from the documentation. Thanks once again for taking time to answer this question
